# Order Entries by Category Fields (with fallback)

Tags: categories, relations, ordering, sorting

This is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7194/order-entries-by-category-field/7196?noredirect=1#comment33302_7196)

I have a section which I want to sort by category field. But the categories are not mandatory.

When I apply `|group('refSorter.first().title')` it will throw an error:

> Key "type" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, and so on"
>   does not exist.

I did a workaround with a conditional statement but I guess there is a DRYer solution:

```
{% set refList = craft.entries.section('referenz') %}
{% set refCategories = craft.categories.group('referenzRubrik').relatedTo(refList) %}

 {% for category in refCategories %}

    <h2>{{ category.title }}</h2>

    {# testing if there is a category slug for preventing a error when no category is asigned #}

    {% if category.slug == 'kantone' %}

      {% for item in refList.relatedTo(category).order('title')|group('refSorter.first().title') %}
          {# this is beeing sorted via category title fields #}
      {% endfor %}

    {% else %}

      {% for item in refList.relatedTo(category).order('title') %}
        {# this is beeing sorted via entry title fields #}
      {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

The must be a better way right?